# How to call an C# program after an insert into Azure table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

I need some architecture guidance here.And if anybody can please give me an overview of how it can be done and i will figure out rest of stuff myself.

1. So from my WINRT App i am capturing an image and  sending the image
   to Azure tables. I am storing image in blob and image path in table.
2. So whenever the image is inserted into azure tables, a service [*or
   whatever it is a bus , a queue..*] should call a C# program [*This
   C# program takes the image and other parameters from table  and does
   shape recognition*].
3. This C# program will run asynchronously and will update the table
   with image matching %.
4. After that Azure  will send an push notification to device if image matching % is greater than 90%. [i know
   this is a simple script].

I know Steps 1 and Steps 4.   How do i do go around with Step 2 and Step 3?.Where should i put my C# program so that azure tables can call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a worker role hosting a WCF service. The worker role host your C# program and take care of step 3 the WCF service will provide the means for step 2 and your flow would look something like:

1. So from my WINRT App i am capturing an image and sending the image to Azure tables. I am storing image in blob and image path in table.
2. Client (WinRT app) makes a call to the WCF service after image is sent to initiate step 3.
3. Web service call executes your shape recognition code asynchronously.
4. After that Azure will send an push notification to device if image matching % is greater than 90%. [i know this is a simple script].

Comment: I'd also recommend considering Windows Azure Mobile Services. It allows for scripting on inserts of data.

Comment: @JeffWilcox Hi Jeff , Actually i am using scripting to send an push notification to client every time insert is made .I was curious how i can call an C# program every on insert and where the C# program be in Azure? So like do i need to have a VM running and Call the C# program in that VM everytime an insert is made?

Comment: Well for notifications Mobile Services has this ability built in, but for more generic support, you can use Queues and/or Service Bus Queues in Azure - push something onto the queue from mobile services (or your app), and then dequeue from your worker process running in Azure.